# Compare Pointers in Virtual Pascal

Tags: pascal

I have to convert some procedures that used inline asm code in Virtual Pascal but don't know how to compare pointers in Virtual Pascal?

Here's example that causes a `Operand types do not match operator` on the `While` statement:

```
procedure ReverseBytes(var V; Size : Word);
{-Reverse the ordering of bytes from V[1] to V[Size]. Size must be >= 2.}
var
    P1, P2 : ^Byte;
    PT : Byte;
begin
    P1 := @V;
    P2 := P1;
    Inc(P2, Size-1);
    
    while (P1 < P2) do
    begin
        PT := P1^;
        P1^ = P2^;
        ^P2 := PT;
        Inc(P1);
        Dec(P2);
    end;
end;
```

How do you compare pointers (themselves - not what they point to) in Virtual Pascal?

P.S. I understand there are some flavors of Pascal (GNU Pascal for example) that support it just like C language (like I do above).  But Virtual Pascal doesn't.

TIA!!

Comment: Dword(P1), and so on, should work.

Comment: I used LongInt since Dword doesn't exist, seems happy.

Comment: Better define something like uintptr =dword centrally and then use that.  If you use dword everywhere, you would have to rewrite it going to a 64-bit system. Some compilers need {$pointermath on}, but afaik Delphi introduced that after VP's demise.

Comment: Historically pointers comparisons were introduced (TP6? with $X+) only for `PChar` pointers, and were intended between two pointers to the same `array of Char`, but this was never enforced _(and much abused, exactly the same as in ISO C)_. So instead of `^Byte`/`PByte`, you might have better luck with `PChar`.